# Content rendering in tabbed content area

Tags: html, css

Good day all.  I'm having an issue getting content to render correctly in one panel of my tabbed content area.  It looks fine in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Del087/9yptj2nj/ however, it is not rendering correctly on my site.  If you look here http://www.realtimehockey.net/canlan.html and check out the second tab "Youth Classic" you should see what I mean.  Ideally I am trying to get the top two elements to align horizontally with the 3rd element below the two.  I'm sure this is a fairly easy fix but, I just can't seem to figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

The CSS

```
<style> td, tr {
border-style: none
}
A {
text-decoration:none
}
a:link {
color: #0000ff;
}
a:visited {
color: #0000ff:
}
a:hover {
color: #ff6600;
}
</style> <style> .tabs input[type=radio] {
display:none;
text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs {
width: 730px;
height: 1100px;
float: none;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
padding: 0px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin: 5px;
margin-top: 2px;
}
.tabs li {
float: left;
}
.tabs label {
display: block;
padding: 10px 20px;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: patua one;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 14px;
background: linear-gradient(#151515, #080808);
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
}
.tabs label:hover {
background: #ff6600;
}
.tab-content {
z-index: 2;
display: none;
left: 0;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 140%;
padding: 5px;
width: 725px;
margin-right: 5px;
position: absolute;
box-sizing: border-box;
border:3px solid #454545;
border-top: 7px solid #454545;
background-color:#080808;
}
[id^=tab]:checked + label {
background: #ff6600;
color: white;
top: 0;
}
[id^=tab]:checked ~[id^=tab-content] {
display: block;
}
</style> <style> #table-wrapper {
position:relative;
}
#table-scroll {
height:965px;
width: auto;
overflow:auto;
margin-top:2px;
}
#table-wrapper table {
width:auto;
}
#table-wrapper table * {
}
#table-wrapper table thead th .text {
position:absolute;
top:-20px;
z-index:2;
height:20px;
width:auto;
}
</style> <style> .table2 {
margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>

The HTML

<ul class="tabs">
<li>
    <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
    <label for="tab1">Tournaments</label>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
        <div id="OrgsAtoD56_5439" align=center x:publishsource="Excel">
            <div id="table-wrapper">
                <div id="table-scroll">
<iframe frameborder="0" height="630" scrolling="no"    src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=704B9036DA9EF5A7&resid=704B9036DA9EF5A7%214256&authkey=ADHo6NDfwBXvj5k&em=2&wdAllowInteractivity=False&Item='Sheet1'!A1%3AF36&wdHideGridlines=True" width="695"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
    <label for="tab2">Youth Classic</label>
    <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
        <div id="table-wrapper">
            <iframe src="https://scorestream.com/widgets/scoreboards/vert?userWidgetId=1317" style="padding:7px;border:0px;width:350px;height:600px;max-height:600px;" title="Realtime sports scoreboard widget" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
            <table border="3" bordercolor="080808" padding="1px" align="right" class="table2">
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/AdsWebsite/Canlan600200_zpszbaycily.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/AdsWebsite/Canlan600200_zpszbaycily.jpg" border="0" alt=" photo Canlan600200_zpszbaycily.jpg"/></a>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <iframe width="664" height="300" style="padding-left:10px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=704B9036DA9EF5A7&resid=704B9036DA9EF5A7%214321&authkey=ADVLgs4SS_FHqAY&em=2&wdAllowInteractivity=False&Item='Sheet1'!A1%3AG57&wdHideGridlines=True"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3">
    <label for="tab3">Niagara Falls Youth Challenge</label>
    <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content">
        <div id="table-wrapper">
            <div id="table-scroll"> <a href="http://www.realtimehockey.net/associations.html" target="_parent"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Website%20Art/RTHConstruction_zpsbyvi5c0d.png" width="720px" border="0" alt=" photo RTHConstruction_zpsbyvi5c0d.png"/></a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab4">
    <label for="tab4">King/Rings I</label>
    <div id="tab-content4" class="tab-content">
        <div id="table-wrapper">
            <div id="table-scroll"> <a href="http://www.realtimehockey.net/associations.html" target="_parent"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Website%20Art/RTHConstruction_zpsbyvi5c0d.png" width="720px" border="0" alt=" photo RTHConstruction_zpsbyvi5c0d.png"/></a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab5">
    <label for="tab5">King/Rings II</label>
    <div id="tab-content5" class="tab-content">
        <div id="table-wrapper">
            <div id="table-scroll"> <a href="http://www.realtimehockey.net/associations.html" target="_parent"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Website%20Art/RTHConstruction_zpsbyvi5c0d.png" width="720px" border="0" alt=" photo RTHConstruction_zpsbyvi5c0d.png"/></a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab6">
    <label for="tab6">CANADA O to Y</label>
    <div id="tab-content6" class="tab-content">
        <div id="table-wrapper">
            <div id="table-scroll"> <a href="http://www.realtimehockey.net/associations.html" target="_parent"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Website%20Art/RTHConstruction_zpsbyvi5c0d.png" width="720px" border="0" alt=" photo RTHConstruction_zpsbyvi5c0d.png"/></a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: If you can't get it to "not" work on a sample, than you should probably try harder to find the difference. Try to use the debugger in your browser to look at the CSS properties of the elements that don't do what you want them to

Answer (score 0):

Your table on [realtimehockey](http://www.realtimehockey.net/canlan.html) on tab2 is embedded in extra

```
<div style="overflow:auto">
    <table>....</table>
</div>
```

element (right after first iframe) in table-wrapper. Browser inserts line break before and after div element by the default. Remove this extra div element and it'll work like on jsfiddle. You can apply styl="display: inline;" to this div and it'll also work.

Comment: thank you for your assistance.  Are you referring to the iframe in "tab 1"?  I did remove the extra <div> tags around the first iframe element in tab 1 but, this didn't fix this issue.  The issue is within "tab 2" and it looks to me the <div> tags are correct there.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I'm so sorry but, I'm not seeing <div style="overflow:auto"> in my code before the table.  In looking at the tab2 content I only see two opening <div> tags.  <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content2">
        <div id="table-wrapper">.  I apologize for my naivety but, I'm still not sure exactly where you are eluding to.

Comment: I'm talking about other link you gave - http://www.realtimehockey.net/canlan.html . Under tab2 just below this <iframe src="https://scorestream.com/widgets/scoreboards/vert?userWidgetId=1317" /> you had a <div style="overflow:auto">, now you have div with display inline, in this div you have the old (offending, the one you should remove or change to display inline - not create a parent) div and inside it there is a table. You should remove or change the one with overflow: auto